# TypeError: Member "mint" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ERC20

Tags: solidity, tokens, openzeppelin, revert-opcode

`token.mint(beneficiary, tokens)` prevents code from fully compiling using Zeppelin 1.8.

Casting your token as a MintableToken* solves this issue and allows your code to compile:

```
MintableToken token = MintableToken(ERC20(token));
token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);
```

*Where 'MintableToken' could be replaced by the name of your token.

However, this causes tests to revert once your code compiles.

Answer (score 3):

The best option to fix your broken tests is to cast following code from the `_deliverTokens` function in Zeppelin's new "MintedCrowdsale.sol"(Zeppelin version 1.8) file in the following way:

```
MintableToken(token).mint(beneficiary, amount);
```

This allows for a compile, passing tests, and casting your token.